# ASP.NET MVC - JsonConvert.DeserializeObject to Html.DropDownList

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, json.net, asp.net-4.5

I'm trying to read some data in as Json, deserialize it, and display it in my view in a DropDownList. The data looks like this:

```
{
  "products": [
    {
      "body_html": "<p> ....</p>",
      "created_at": "2012-09-19T11:55:44-04:00",
      ...
      "tags": "Emotive, Flash Memory, MP3, Music",
      "variants": [
        {
          "compare_at_price": null,
          "created_at": "2012-09-19T11:55:44-04:00",
          ...
          "inventory_quantity": 10
        }
      ],
      "images": [
        {
          "created_at": "2012-09-19T11:55:44-04:00",
          "id": 850703190,
          ...
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I've tried a few different things which haven't worked. Right now I have in my controller:

```
var data = Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject.Parse(productsJson.ToString())["products"];
SelectList productsData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SelectList>(data.ToString());
ViewData["products"] = productsData;
```

And in the view:

```
@Html.DropDownList("ProductList", (SelectList)ViewData["products"])
```

Presently I'm getting the following error:

> Cannot create and populate list type System.Web.Mvc.SelectList.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
>   the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: Cannot create and
>   populate list type System.Web.Mvc.SelectList.

Help is appreciated.

Comment: What text are you trying to put in the select list?  I don't see any good candidates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you should parse json to your product type then you may use like this:

```
var products = new SelectList(parsedProductList,"valueField here", "textField here");
```

Answer (score 1):

I give you another solution's to fill your dropdownlist with json

in my controller i have a action and fill my state with country selection

public JsonResult State(int countryId)
    {

```
    var stateList = CityRepository.GetList(countryId);
    return Json(stateList, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

in my view i bind my state dropdownlist like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function cascadingdropdown() {
        $("#stateID").empty();
        $("#stateID").append("<option value='0'>--Select State--</option>");
        var countryID = $('#countryID').val();
        $.ajax({
            url: "/City/State",
            dataType: 'json',
            data: { countryId: countryID },
            success: function (data) {
                $("#stateID").empty();
                $("#stateID").append("<option value='0'>--Select State--</option>");
                $.each(data, function (index, optiondata) {
                    alert(optiondata.StateName);
                    $("#stateID").append("<option value='" + optiondata.ID + "'>" + optiondata.StateName + "</option>");
                });
            },
            error: function () {
                alert('Faild To Retrieve states.');
            }

        });
    } 
</script>
```

i think this will help you ...

Answer (score 0):

`products` in your JSON is not compatible with `SelectList` type.
Try to fill in SelectList manually.